Simple future for a decided plan (2)

Context 1:


A: Do you have plans tonight?
B: Yes, I’ll watch/ 'm going to watch/'m watching/ 'll be watching a movie on Netflix with my friend tonight. Would you like to join us?

=> in this post, Native speakers tell me that in this context, because watching a movie is a decided plan, the version I'll watch ( will watch) sounds unnatural,

Context 2:


A: I'm going to visit Paris next month.
B: That sounds great. Where will you stay in Paris?
A: I’ll stay in a small hotel. I already book the hotel in advance
to save money.

As I see " Where will you stay in Paris?" is also asking about a decided plan. And " I’ll stay in a small hotel." is also talking about a decided plan too.
Does using the simple future - 'll (will) in this context in the question and the answer above  sound unnatural as in the way we use "ll watch" in the context 1?
People tell me that using the simple future to refer to a personal plan isn't idiomatic. If so, "Where will you stay in Paris?" and "I’ll stay in a small hotel" in this context 2 don't sound natural. Right?

B's question is OK, though they might also ask "Where are you staying?" A would reply "I'm staying/going to stay..." (and "I've already booked the hotel").

@KateBunting why the simple future sound unnatural in the context 1, but it sound fine in the context 2

As I see, both context refer to a plan

I don't think a native speaker would use "I will do this" when speaking of plans for later the same day, but it's a little more natural (I didn't say 'fine') when talking about a trip a month from now.  This isn't a 'rule', just the way people use the language.

@KateBunting, if so, does this sentence with simple future still sound natural?: “I will visit Paris next month. Would you like to go with me?”

It's not grammatically wrong, but "I shall be visiting Paris" or "I'm going to visit Paris" are more idiomatic.

If so,  "I will visit Paris" talking about plan and "I 'll stay in a small hotel?" in the context 2 don't idiomatic. Right? @KateBunting

No, they aren't very idiomatic.

"I will visit Paris" could be the emphatic use of "will", used to express determination.

Once, I made a mistake when I was with a native friend of mine. As an apology, I went "It's not gonna happen again.". He corrected me "It won't happen again.". Despite this fact that I'm planning not to make that mistake again but I understood that I should have used "will" instead of "going to" in this situation.

I'm not sure if you consider Woodward English to be a reputable source, but it does a good job of laying out the differences. Here's a summary in the context of your questions.
You use going to or watching when you're speaking about plans that have already been decided, i.e. plans you made prior to having the conversation.

A: Do you have plans tonight?
B: Yes, I'm going to watch a movie on Netflix with my friend tonight. Would you like to join us?
or
B: Yes, I'm watching a movie on Netflix with my friend...

To me, watching is just ever so slightly more set in stone than going to.
If instead, you made up the plans on the spot at the time of the conversation, i.e. they were a spontaneous decision, then will can be used, but so can going to:

A: Do you have plans tonight?
B: Hmmm, I think I'll watch a movie on Netflix with my friend...
or
B: Hmmmm, I think I'm going to watch a movie with my friend...

It would also be appropriate if you had several options to choose from, and you were deciding at that moment which one to pick. For example:

B: I can either go swimming with Peter or watch a movie on Netflix. I'll probably watch a movie on Netflix because Peter is such a bore!

The answer is similar for your second context. Since you've already booked the reservation, the plans have been decided upon, which calls for going to or staying.
Also, if you were visiting a person, you would say "I'm going to visit Vivian." But if you're going to visit Paris, you just say "I'm going to Paris."

A: I'm going to visit Paris next month.
B: That sounds great. Where are you staying in Paris?
or
B: Where are you going to stay in Paris?
A: I’m staying in a small hotel. I already booked the hotel in advance to save money.
or
A: I'm going to stay in a small hotel....

Again, to me, staying is very slightly more definitive than going to stay.
For will:

A: I'm going to visit Paris next month.
B: That sounds great. Where are you staying in Paris?
A: I'm not sure. I'll decide when I get there.
or
A: I'm not sure. I'm going to decide when I get there.

There are additional examples on the source page I provided that describe other scenarios when you would typically use one over the other.


If so, in the context that I already have plan, I can't use " I’ll watch..."
